# Formula to reference a cell but not update with that cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My workbook has data that is automatically loaded in from yahoo finance. The data is constantly being refreshed. I need a formula that can take the referenced cell and produce the number value of that cell without updating whenever the referenced cell does. For example: Cell G3 will say 40.75 for the stock value and I need D2 to say 40.75 except that it will remain 40.75 when G3 updates to the new price.

I have tried using =Numbervalue($G$3) but that still updates when the data refreshes.

Comment: This is easy with a **VBA** macro..............are you O.K. with this approach??

Comment: If I automate this thing with a VBA Macro that'd be awesome. I haven't got the slightest clue how to approach it from that angle though.